# Mongodb: Store c# list of objects to mongo

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization

I have a c# class with property of type `List<object>`.

```
public class Result
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Table{get;set;}
    public List<object> TableHeaderKey {get;set;}
    public List<LocationVariance> locationVariance { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to save this to mongo collection

```
public async Task<T> Add<T>(T obj, string collectionName)
{
    var session = __client.StartSession();
    var document = obj.ToBsonDocument();
    session.StartTransaction();
    var collection = __database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    session.CommitTransaction();            
}
```

The values get stored in db but the values for property TableHeaderKey is gets stored as below.

```
"TableHeaderKey" : [
                            {
                                "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
                                "_v" : {
                                    "Item" : {
                                        "_t" : "JArray",
                                        "_v" : [
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
                                "_v" : {
                                    "Description" : {
                                        "_t" : "JArray",
                                        "_v" : [
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
                                "_v" : {
                                    "Delivery" : {
                                        "_t" : "JArray",
                                        "_v" : [
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_t" : "JValue",
                                                "_v" : [ ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
```

Values for TableHeaderKey property.

```
"tableHeaderKey": [
                {
                    "Line": [
                        136,
                        242,
                        1179,
                        1213
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Supplier Part / Item Number": [
                        265,
                        760,
                        1177,
                        1219
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Item Description": [
                        949,
                        1245,
                        1179,
                        1219
                    ]
                }
                {
                    "Unit Price": [
                        1991,
                        2183,
                        1179,
                        1213
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Line Total": [
                        2212,
                        2403,
                        1178,
                        1213
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

And while fetching the value from mongo getting below error:

System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the TableHeaderKey property of class Result: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method. ---> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method. at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`2.FinalizeResult(Object accumulator) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DiscriminatedWrapperSerializer`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(String elementName, Int64 flag) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerHelper.DeserializeMembers(BsonDeserializationContext context, Action`2 memberHandler)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest converting your JSON to `BsonDocument` and `BsonArray` objects and then sotre them in the database that way.

Comment: @Llama: i am converting it to BsonDocument before storing to db. ` var document = obj.ToBsonDocument();`

Comment: @Llama I have also tried this ` var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));` but in this case, if the document has a date fields, it will store date as a string type in mongo.

Comment: Then if it's such an issue, why don't you create classes that represent your JSON?